# Access Query resulting in #Error for one outcome

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am pulling information via a query in access. Below is my code. The results populate when the `"Pinacle Type" is "DOM" or "BOOK"`, but if the type is anything else, as stated by the IIF statement, I get *#Error*.

```
5_BeneBankID: IIf([Pinacle_Type]="DOM" Or "BOOK",Mid(Replace(Replace([BeneABA]," ",""),"-",""),1,11),Mid(Replace(Replace([Intl_BeneBankID]," ",""),"-",""),1,11))
```

Embedded in this statement is are also formatting parts but those work for the first instance. The BeneABA field is a bank ABA number so this is always numeric. The Intl_BeneBankID is what is known as a SWIFT code which is either all alpha or alphanumeric. Both have a maximum length of 11 characters.

Also, If I type the following, the Intl_BeneBankID POPULATES! which is why I am stumped:

5_BeneBankID: Intl_BeneBankID

relevant table

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but I think `[Pinacle_Type]="DOM" Or "BOOK"` should read `[Pinacle_Type]="DOM" Or [Pinacle_Type]="BOOK"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, as your description of the problem seems vague to me, but if you are getting #error on some rows, but not all, you probably have null fields in your data.  This is a common problem in test data, not so often in production code, but needs to be handled.  Try wrapping the fields with Nz() i.e. ((Replace(Nz([Intl_BeneBankID],"")... and see what you get.